# A question on complex functions $f$ with $Re(\bar{z}f(z)) > 0$ on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function from an open set $U$ containing the closed unit disk into complex numbers. Suppose that for any $z$ with $|z| = 1$, $Re(\bar{z}f(z)) > 0$. Show that $f$ has only one root in the closed unit disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Re(\bar zf(z))$ is the inner product of $z$ and $f(z)$ (if we identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$), your condition thus means that the angle between $z$ and $f(z)$ is acute. We can thus deform $f$, as a map from the unit circle to $\mathbb C-\{0\}$, to the identity map - for example via $h(z,t):=tz+(1-t)f(z)$, $h(z,t)\neq0$ for all $0\leq t\leq1$, $|z|=1$. By the argument principle $f$ has one root in the unit disc.